# I have a problem wiht installing GQLalchemy on Mac

Tags: memgraphdb

On my laptop I'm running MacOS. I use ZSH as my shell. I'm new to Python world and to Memegraph. I'm just setting up my dev enviroment. When I try to install GQLAlchemy using PIP

`pip install gqlalchemy[arrow]` but it doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For zsh terminal, you need to pass literal square brackets as an argument to a command:
`pip install 'gqlalchemy[arrow]'`